# Showing a specific character in mysql for count() and display it

Tags: mysql

I have this code which is trying to show the count of username which has description value of 'Yes' only

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, COUNT(description) 
FROM products GROUP BY username
```

*which I trying to add//WHERE description = 'Yes'

But it shows and count all the data in description.

I only want to show the description count with value of 'Yes'

Comment: You code, i think,  actually tries to show the list of 'unique' usernames that have any product with a 'description' of 'yes'.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes u r right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
 SELECT count(*),username
 FROM products
  WHERE
  description LIKE '%Yes%'
  or
 description LIKE '%yes%'
 GROUP BY username
```

Comment: okay its working now, you had a space there before "yes"
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ab1/5

Comment: wow, thanks my friend!! it works, but one more thing wanna ask,what should I add if I wanna put the description with bigger number of description place at the first place?

Comment: no problem
you mean "yes" is shorter and "yesthesearemorecharacters" is bigger ?

Comment: what I mean is with larger number of count, means when username of a have description 3, so it will place at 1st place and 2nd is description with 1. Now is another way, I should put ASC?

Comment: check if this works?
  SELECT count(*) as c,username
     FROM products
      WHERE
      description LIKE '%Yes%'
      or
     description LIKE '%yes%'
     GROUP BY username
     ORDER BY c DESC

Comment: I tried, what is the c, new variable right? I want to use PHP to display my table in a way like this,  username "a" | description "3" and following by username " "| description 1. How can I do that?

Comment: "c" was temporary or selection "title" or "alias" for description count . for this format use this query
    SELECT username,count(*) as description
     FROM products
      WHERE
      description LIKE '%Yes%'
      or
     description LIKE '%yes%'
     GROUP BY username
     ORDER BY description DESC

Comment: it works in the mysql, but not when I display it.
I fetch my data with this line in PHP, anything extra I need to put?
$product["description"] = $row["count(*)"];

Comment: plz give me a favor, if this format and other rhings works by my comment plz add it to new question and i wll past theses as answer so you can accept that too

Comment: give me time to provide you with php, meanwhile you can someup this 2nd issue in new question if possible

Comment: okay provide me with the url of question, will post view and updated answer there when will type it completly

Comment: here you go my friend.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575711/mysql-asc-the-data-of-the-existing-mysql-query

Comment: have posted basic answer, try it it will need some changes may be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63702/discussion-between-confuser-and-abdul-basit).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you ....

```
SELECT count(*),username
FROM products 
WHERE description = 'yes'
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: it doesn't show any result in my phpmyadmin, do u know how this happen? It runs but it doesn't show result like what I want.