# mysql, ASC the data of the existing mysql query

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need help on this data if I have this query

```
SELECT count(*),username
FROM products
WHERE
description LIKE '%Yes%'
or
description LIKE '%yes%'
GROUP BY username
```

I need to ASC this data so that it will appear my data as this

```
username    |    description
 a          |      3
 b          |      1
```

and this is my PHP code which I want to show it and display it on my android apps.

```
 $result = mysql_query("

 SELECT count(*),username
 FROM products
 WHERE
 description LIKE '%Yes%'
or
description LIKE '%yes%'
GROUP BY username

" ) or die(mysql_error()); 



// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
   $product = array();
    $product["username"] = $row["username"];
    $product["description"] = $row["count(*)"];

    array_push($response["products"], $product);

}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Your help is Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if it works

```
  $sql = "SELECT username,count(*) as description
  FROM products
  WHERE
  description LIKE '%Yes%'
  or
 description LIKE '%yes%'
 GROUP BY username
 ORDER BY description ASC";

 $q = mysql_query($sql);
 echo mysql_num_rows($q);
 $output = "<table>";
   $output .= "<td>";
   $output .= "Description";
   $output .= "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>";
   $output .= "Username";
   $output .= "</td>";
   $output .= "</tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   $output .= "<tr>";
   $output .= "<td>";
   $output .= $row["description"];
   $output .= "</td>";
   $output .= "<td>";
   $output .= $row["username"];
   $output .= "</td>";

   $output .="</tr>";
   }

   $output .="</table>";
   echo $output;
```

if you want this to be in json finally to send it to android

```
  $sql = "SELECT username,count(*) as description
  FROM products
  WHERE
  description LIKE '%Yes%'
  or
 description LIKE '%yes%'
 GROUP BY username
 ORDER BY description ASC";

 $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $product = array(); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    { 


    $product[]["username"] = $row["username"];
    $product[]["description"] = $row["description"];
    }
    echo json_encode($product);
```

this will give you output like this

```
 [{"username":"a"},{"description":"3"},{"username":""},{"description":"1"}]
```

if you want sort with respect to username instead of descripton, change the query to

```
 $sql = "SELECT username,count(*) as description
  FROM products
  WHERE
  description LIKE '%Yes%'
  or
 description LIKE '%yes%'
 GROUP BY username
 ORDER BY username ASC";
```

Comment: Hi, my friend,I couldn't get it works. I'm using this for my code now.

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

       $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["username"] = $row["username"];
        $product["description"] = $row["count(description)"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);

Comment: I'm fetching the php using json to my android coding to display the table.

Comment: edited and working perfectly now for me, just style your table now (Y)

Comment: so you dont want it to be in html?

Comment: and you said you just want username and description but in comment there is also id,created_at, etc colomns

Comment: Ya, my friend, I want to pass it into my apps for it. Have no idea yet. If the previous query I able to display, if I want it to be in ASC like this one, it's not working.

Comment: That one you can ignore it, I will delete it away afterwards.

Comment: for json i have edited the answer, you can echo this for json, but further for android i dont have any idea about android

Comment: it doesn't work my friend, maybe I try it again first... I edit the question, u can see how it looks. I think it's only related php and mysql..

Comment: thanks!!! it works, thanks for your time my friend, do I have the honor to ask u again in any social media sites next time?

Comment: Hi mr @AbdulBasit, can you help me solve the final question? it's the easiest though. Thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576638/mysql-asc-a-series-of-number-using-existed-data

Comment: no problem at all ! fb(dot)com/ab.abdulbasit.. currently deactivated but will be bac in few days

Comment: great!! Will get it touch with you! Thank you very much my friend!