# mysql, ASC a series of number using existed data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Good day, I have this query which arrange my data in order of higher number

```
SELECT username,count(*) as description
FROM products
WHERE
description LIKE '%Yes%'

or

description LIKE '%yes%'
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY description ASC
```

which will bring me this outcome

```
username  |   description
   a      |     3
   b      |     1
```

I'm able to do the above, question is what should I do in order to make it like this?

```
 rank   |   username    |  description
  1     |     a         |    3
  2     |     b         |    1
```

new column, rank, which is a fixed 1,2,3 that won't change while the username and description name change.

Comment: the rank is just serial no? thats incremented on each count?

Comment: Ya, just a fixed increment of count.

Comment: I tried just now, no luck yet, I will try again, it's late night here, I will have few more questions to ask again my friend, really zillion thanks to you, u save my life again.. For this answer I will try again in the morning in my place.

Comment: no problem okay , i ma getting downvotes for the answer between :p

Comment: Hi my friend @AbdulBasit, I wanna ask, if I can change those number of description into a small image or badge for each number?

Comment: for example description= " 1 " it will shows description = "♥" and description = "2" will be description =" ♥ ♥"

Comment: Hi, my friend, @AbdulBasit if you still here, can you help me in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614427/turn-number-in-tables-into-an-image-and-also-display-asc-number-in-mysql-using-p

Comment: let me see, i think i saw your ques was busy so didnt answered let mee see if i can

Comment: it's okay, my friend, sorry for disturbing, this will be the final part of my assignment. the link will solved all my assignment's problem. :)

Comment: Thanks!!! Take your time my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are sometimes issues when using variables with `group by`.  I'm not sure if this affects counting variables, but it definitely affects running sums.  A safer approach is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank, username, numdescription
FROM (SELECT p.username, count(*) as numdescription
      FROM products p
      WHERE description LIKE '%Yes%' or description LIKE '%yes%'
      GROUP BY p.username
     ) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY numdescription DESC;
```

Note that I renamed the output field.  Using the same name seems confusing, because one is a description (string) and the other is a count (number).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a variable with initial value equal to zero and incremented  by 1 for each row. 
Try the following query

```
SELECT  @n:=@n+1 as rank,username,count(*) as description
FROM products,(SELECT @n:= 0) AS num
WHERE
description LIKE '%Yes%'
or
description LIKE '%yes%'
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY description ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

add count while extracting the data from mysql fetch to the array in which you are storing

for example

```
$count = 1;

$product = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{ 

$count[]['rank'] = $count;
$product[]["username"] = $row["username"];
$product[]["description"] = $row["description"];
$count++;
}
```