# Turn number in tables into an image and also display ASC number in mysql using PHP

Tags: android, mysql, android-layout

I wanted to ask based on this query which I have.

```
SELECT username,count(*) as description
FROM products
WHERE
description LIKE '%Yes%'

or

description LIKE '%yes%'
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY description ASC
```

For your information, the outcome will be like this.

```
username  |   description
   a      |     3
   b      |     1
```

I wanted to ask if I can make it into this form?

```
rank   | username  |   description
  1    |      a    |     ♥ ♥ ♥
  2    |      b    |     ♥
```

The ♥ will be an image, not any symbol, can blob achieve this? What can I do to do this?

In my previous question, [mysql, ASC a series of number using existed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576638/mysql-asc-a-series-of-number-using-existed-data?noredirect=1#comment41771378_26576638) , some of the members give me this, but how can I apply into my PHP code to display in my android XML?

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank, username, numdescription
FROM (SELECT p.username, count(*) as numdescription
  FROM products p
  WHERE description LIKE '%Yes%' or description LIKE '%yes%'
  GROUP BY p.username
 ) p CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY numdescription DESC;
```

Comment: Why can't you just fix the presentation in your application layer? Doing this in the database is annoying.

Comment: do you get data in this form in android?
[{"username":"a"},{"description":"3"},{"username":""},{"description":"1"}]

Comment: Ya, it does get.. just to change number into image. :) that's it.